# The Viper is coming

Tags: history, pun

Needed 50 years to "get" the joke, or better, not the joke itself but the reference. New record. German comedian Otto made it ("I'V CAMM TO VIP YOUR VINDOV!"), and I always thought his "Viper" poem skit referenced to something from "high" literature, Poe or whatnot.  Until *Teen Titans Go!* brought the same joke, and I learnt the viper/wiper pun is an old school (Halloween?) gag.

So much, so undetailed - can anyone tell me the earliest known reference of this gag? And maybe it *really* also occured somewhere in "higher" literature? (Otto really overacted as if reading "The Raven" or so...)

Comment: I first heard this joke reading the 1981 book *Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark*.  The author acknowledges that many of these stories are based on folklore.  It's likely that the joke predates this book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about the history of a joke that happens to involve mishearing a foreign accent, but otherwise has nothing to do with learning English.